# WaTiN issue - WaTin Freezes C# Application

Tags: c#, watin

I've just created a Winform in C# that uses WaTiN. The program works fine but whenever it opens new WaTiN browser windows in the background and navigates to a page etc. the application it freezes over and can't be used until WaTiN has finished its processes. Can you please help me to prevent this. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use background workers. The behaviour you're experiencing is absolutely normal. You can start reading about the workers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58292/Basic-Backgroundworker).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out those pages.